# sed won't perform the required subs inside shell script

Tags: shell, sed

In the below shell script I try to print `A2D(Vlog-Ams-@Cross)` with special characters escaped. For example replace `(` with `\(` but sed won't have any effect.

```
#! /bin/sh
parameter="A2D(Vlog-Ams-@Cross)"
echo $parameter
parameterz=`echo "$parameter" | sed 's/(/\\(/g'`
echo $parameterz
```

The output is

```
A2D(Vlog-Ams-@Cross)
A2D(Vlog-Ams-@Cross)
```

If I do the same on my c-shell terminal, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You use backslashs within a backtick command and that's tricky. If the sed command didn't occur within backticks, it would work correctly. When the shell looks for the closing backtick, however, it removes one level of backslash quoting, so you get

```
sed 's/(/\(/g'
```

and that's a no-op. If your shell permits it, use `$(...)` instead of backticks; in this way you avoid these quoting problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your replacement `\\(` the first `\` escapes the second `\`. But you must escape the `(`, too:

```
$  echo 'A2D(Vlog-Ams-@Cross)' | sed -e 's/(/\\\(/g' -e 's/)/\\\)/g'
A2D\(Vlog-Ams-@Cross\)
```

Comment: It would be more convenient to put the characters to escape in a character group: `... | sed 's:[)(]:\\\&:g'`.